# USB to 2.4v receiver power reducer

Tags: usb

I am trying to power a small receiver with a USB pack it shows 5v coming from the USB and it says max 3.5v coming into the receiver. I know somewhere there is an inline reducer to step down as not to damage the receiver. Plugs are USB to 2.1mm plug. I think I just need to find a small reducer and solder it inline. Does anyone have any feedback on it?

Note: I have been using two D cells to power the receiver for a long time, but they drain too fast.

Comment: Please, provide a visual illustration of what you want to connect to what, it would really help (at worst, draw in paint)

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for something called a [_voltage regulator_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator) (possibly less efficient) or a [DC-to-DC converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter) (possibly more efficient). But, if you want to get any kind of a meaningful answer, you probably should tell people how much _power_ this receiver of yours needs.

Comment: I did, its say 3.5 max volts. but I have been powering it with 2 d cells giving it 2.4v

Comment: @Lightboximages Power and voltage are different things.  Your question has been flagged for lack of details, and will be closed if you do not provide them since we cannot help without more information.

Comment: Close it I figured it out myself. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your resources or skill set I will take a SWAG: You state a small battery operated receiver, so I am assuming it is not a big power user. There are many ways you can go. You can search Aliexpress, azon, and others for step down module. Also searching for "3V from USB" will yield a lot of results. They also make wall warts with the 3v3 output voltage or 5V USB power. They also make USB to TTL cables that have a 3.3V output, maybe that would work. Let us know how it works for you.

Comment: Yes is a receiver that can take a max v of 3.5V and I want to use a USB battery pack that puts out 5V so I will check out the lead you mentioned. Thanks